# Javascript data transformation

Tags: javascript, lodash

Input:

```
     {
    "8": [{
        "a": true,
        "b": {
            "xyz": 1
        }
    }, {
        "a": false,
        "b": {
            "xyz": 2
        }
    }],
    "13": [{
        "b": {
            "xyz": 4
        }
    }]
 }
```

Output:

```
    {
    "8": [{
        "b": {
            "xyz": 2
        }
    }]
 }
```

How can remove first element of each key and return the few keys of the same object using javascript and lodash library?

Comment: you can remove the first element of an array with array.shift

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but how about above input and output. I need to remove first element of each key and return same object. If only 1 element then need to remove that element itself.

Comment: Anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the entries returned by [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like this:

```js
let obj={"8":[{"a":!0,"b":{"xyz":1}},{"a":!1,"b":{"xyz":2}}],"13":[{"b":{"xyz":4}}]}

let output = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if(value.length > 1)
    acc[key] = value.slice(1)
  
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

If you want to mutate the original object, loop through the object using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) like this:

```js
let obj={"8":[{"a":!0,"b":{"xyz":1}},{"a":!1,"b":{"xyz":2}}],"13":[{"b":{"xyz":4}}]}

for (let key in obj) {
  obj[key].shift()
  if (obj[key].length === 0)
    delete obj[key]
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: "How can remove first element of each key and **return the same object**", I believe OP wants the original object mutated

Comment: Yeah, seems that work and what if I need only certain keys of the object. For example, I only need key `b`. updated output

Comment: @mhodges, Thanks for your response, can you let me know how I can get certain keys? In your output, you are returning keys a and b both any other ways to get certain keys.

Comment: @adiga, did not get you. I'm referring code with reducer.

Comment: @adiga, pls. check my question. In output, I only need object with key b not key a.  I think you misunderstood my questions.

Comment: so how can I remove key - a from below object and return remaining object  {
  "8": [{
    "a": false,
    "b": {
     "xyz": 2
    }
   },
   {
    "a": false,
    "b": {
     "xyz": 3
    }
   }

  ]
 }

Comment: @JwalinShah please create a [mcve] with a clear problem statement. You asked how to remove the first item from each array property. Now you're asking something to do with the nested object's property `b`. Please update the question or ask a new question.

Comment: I appreciate your help @adiga

Answer (score 2):

Without loadash do with [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and `Array#foreach`

1. First convert obj to array using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
2. Then loop the value .And remove the first index of array using `Array#shift`
3. Then apply condition with array length is 0 remove the key value pair from main object

```js
var obj = { "8": [{ "a": true, "b": { "xyz": 1 } }, { "a": false, "b": { "xyz": 2 } }], "13": [{ "b": { "xyz": 4 } }] };
Object.keys(obj).forEach(a => {
  obj[a].shift()
  obj[a] = obj[a];
  if(obj[a].length == 0)
   delete obj[a];
});
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This is not the desired output

Comment: @mhodges now check

Comment: Looks good now. You could save yourself the `shift()` if you check length at the start of the loop, like mine does. It's an extremely small optimization, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)'s `_.flow()` with `_.partialRight()` to create a function that maps the values to the tail (all items but the 1st) of each array, and then uses `_.omitBy()` to remove empty keys:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, mapValues, tail, omitBy, isEmpty } = _

const fn = flow(
  pr(mapValues, tail),
  pr(omitBy, isEmpty)
)

const data = {"8":[{"a":true,"b":{"xyz":1}},{"a":false,"b":{"xyz":2}}],"13":[{"b":{"xyz":4}}]}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the terser [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) version:

```js
const { flow, mapValues, tail, omitBy, isEmpty } = _

const fn = flow(
  mapValues(tail),
  omitBy(isEmpty)
)

const data = {"8":[{"a":true,"b":{"xyz":1}},{"a":false,"b":{"xyz":2}}],"13":[{"b":{"xyz":4}}]}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```